# Problem with starting unity om chromebook

Tags: ubuntu, chromebook, crouton, geoclue

I have installed crouton on my Chromebook and tried to start up unity but get the following result every time:

```
Unknown username "geoclue" in message bus configuration file
-su: 1: enter-croot: not found
Unmounting /mnt/stateful_partition/crouton/chroots/xenial...
```

Can anyone please explain?

Comment: Fixed grammar & Improved formatting

Answer (score 0):

you no longer need to use crouton to run linux apps natively through a chromebook.

Here's a [link](https://medium.com/@alexanderhaskins/unity3d-is-running-natively-on-my-chromebook-and-i-couldnt-be-happier-512a0c4b5e32) that will explain how to do so and will likely mitigate this error.